# Dynamic adapter pathForType based on auth id

Tags: ember-data, firebase, emberfire

Is there any way to include a user's authentication uid in a model adapter's path? For example, suppose you have a chat application, and a `conversation` model to represent a private message session between two users, where the data is stored something like this:

```
{
    "conversations": {
        "<userAuthUID>": {
            "convo1": {...},
            "convo2": {...},
            ...
        },
        "<anotherUserAuthUID>": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So, with this structure, the adapter's path would need to be `conversations/<currentUserAuthUID>`.

(FYI this is an ember-cli project, if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working using the following:

```js
// adapters/conversation.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    pathForType: function(type) {
        //get the firebase authentication data via the `Firebase` instance
        //that i have injected into my app via an initializer
        var authData = this.container.lookup('app:firebase').getAuth();

        return  Ember.String.pluralize(type) + '/' + authData.uid;
    }
});
```